# php redirect when wrong password

Tags: php, html, redirect, authentication

is this right the code will redirect a person to the login page when they try to access it using without going into the login page

```
<?php

$pass = 'password';

?>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

if ( $_POST["pass"] == $pass){
?>

Congrats you have log in!


<?php 

}else{

header("Location: http://signin.com/");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

i ended up having a "Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.test.com It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

Comment: there is no test.html in your code... what you are trying to do

Comment: This looks like your results page, what does the form post page look like?

Comment: the passing of the variable is correct its the method of redirect i'm not sure of.

Comment: This doesn't pertain to your exact question, but you should, as a bare minimum, store only a *hash* of the password and compare that to the hash of `$_POST["pass"]`. As it stands, if you make a mistake that causes the PHP file to be sent without being parsed, your password will be exposed for everyone to see. (This has happened to at least one major website before and it can certainly happen to you.) An even better solution would be to use a database (i.e. SQL) for authentication, but that's beyond the scope of your question for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work better:

```
<?php
$pass = 'password';

if ($_POST["pass"] != $pass){
    header("Location: http://signin.com/");
    exit;
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
Congrats you have log in!

</body>
</html>
```

You need to check if the user is logged in. If not, redirect and exit. If so, display the message.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `header` after you've already outputted some HTML. Do your password checks & redirect. above the HTML

Eg:

```
<?php 
$pass = 'password';
if ( $_POST["pass"] != $pass){
    header("Location: http://signin.com/");
    exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
....
```

So the HTML will only show if they're successful.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send a `header()` after any output to the user:

```
<?php
    $pass = 'password';
    if ( $_POST["pass"] == $pass)
    {
        ?>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>

        Congrats you have log in!

        </body>
        </html>

        <?php 
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: http://signin.com/");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put ob_start(); at the top and ob_end_flush(); and that might fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't output html before make a redirect with `header`. Code all logic before:

```
<?php 
$pass = 'password';

if ($_POST["pass"] == $pass)
{
    $message = "Congrats you have log in!";
}
else
{
    header("Location: http://signin.com/");
}
?>  

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $message; ?>
</body>
```